# How do I extract title of a website?

Tags: php, title, page-title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

How do I extract title of a website using PHP?

Comment: Are you referring to the HTML title e.g. <head><title>VALUE</title></head> ?  If so you should be setting that on the server side when the response goes back.

Answer (score 5):

To manupulate with HTML you can use [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (this is the recomended way).

If you are looking for a dirty fast solution, it's rather simple regexp:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$matches = preg_match("/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/im");
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: could at least have shown the undirty version with DOM then (which is just one LOC more). Now the OP will copy and paste the Regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the domain name through `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: doubtful if OP refers to domain name though.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the document using [curl](http://php.net/curl), run it through [a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) and then use whatever API that parser provides to get the title element (`//title` will do if there is XPath support).