# Grabbing title of a website using DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get title of website via link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348912/get-title-of-website-via-link)
>   [How do I extract title of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869088/how-do-i-extract-title-of-a-website)

How can a website's title be grabbed using PHP DOM? (Which is the best way to grab it using PHP?)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the getElementByTagName() since there is technically only a single title attribute in your html so you can just grab the first one you come across in DOM.

```
$title = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();

if($dom->loadHTMLFile($urlpage)) {
    $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
    if ($list->length > 0) {
        $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds and gave a slightly better example. Removed my answer :)

Comment: @Erik Cheers. Unfortunately, SO feels like a race sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

Suppresses any parsing errors from incorrect HTML or missing elements:

```
<?

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents("http://www.washingtonpost.com"));

// find the title
$titlelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
if($titlelist->length > 0){
  echo $titlelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
 }
```

Comment: `loadHTMLFile` already incorporates file_get_contents and does not give errors on malformed HTML so any errors it does produce would be valuable. `loadHTML` also does not give errors on malformed HTML.

Comment: Well, when I use `$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.washingtonpost.com");
` right now I get a bunch of errors that say *Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://www.washingtonpost.com, line: 52 in /var/www/test/test2.php on line 5*. Maybe its my PHP version, but...

Comment: Your right - my apologies. I was remembering that it will parse it, but it does indeed show warnings. However, the @ suppression method is still a bad choice. You'd be better off setting `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` so you could access the error data if you wanted/needed to

Comment: Point: this was quick and dirty. It IS a little lazy using the error suppression, and I wasn't aware it was using libxml under the hood.