# retrieving the title of a remote page

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a little problem with the pattern for retrieving the title of the remote page while same pattern is giving the result here is the sample.

```
preg_match_all('|<title>(.*)</title>|U',$this->data,$title);
```

is for other url and giving the result .
While following return the empty array

```
preg_match_all('|<title>(.*)</title>|U', $valD, $title);
```

can any on tell me the is any problem with these lines.

Where $this->data and $valD holds the content of two different urls for different servers.

Please help me. I tried it to solve it but I failed to solve it.
So I requesting the you all to tell me my faults in this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser to convert the document into DOM and then use DOM traversal methods or XPath.

Comment: Have you initialized `$title` to an empty array? Have you turned on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE)`)?

Comment: The problem must be that your regex isn't matching for one site - Can you post the snippet of HTML that isn't matching which includes the <title> tag for that page?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexen is brittle. Don't do it except if you have absolute control over the remote page AND only for elements which can't nest recursively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing title of a website using DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869925/grabbing-title-of-a-website-using-dom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are matching HTML, then you should also expect uppercase tags. Add the `|i` flag therefore.

The title tag might also contain newlines, which is why the `|s` flag should also be present.

```
 preg_match_all('|<title>(.*)</title>|Uis', ...
```

Comment: and what if someone does: <title >stuff</ title>?

Comment: @nalply: It would simply not match.

Comment: Also, using `|` as a regex delimiter is not a good idea. Better use a character that's not also a regex metacharacter. `%...%` or  `~...~` come to mind.

Comment: @mario, of course and that's an example why regexen are brittle :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a line break in the title tag such like this:

```
<title>
The page title
</title>
```

Try

```
preg_match_all('|<title>[:space:]*(.*)[:space:]*</title>|U', $valD, $title);
```

instead.

Comment: and what if someone does <Title> instead of <title>? :-)