# I need to check if the keywords exists in the title of a website PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-match, strpos

Can anyone help me here? I’m trying to make a program that checks if a keyword is found on the title of a website. Like the keywords are stored in a variable $keywords and I'd like to check if they exist in $title. The keywords can vary in numbers and they are usually separated by commas. How do I do that? I'm using php by the way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it in your own website or a website that you must fetch the content ?

Comment: i'm getting the data from external websites.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a word is found in a string:

```
function found_keyword($keyword, $title) {
    return preg_match('/' . $keyword . '/', $title);
}
```

(I used preg_match because you had that tag in your question, but I guess there are simpler functions to just check the occurence of a substring in a string)

To check if at least one word in an array of words is found in a string:

```
function found_keywords($keywords, $title) {
    return array_reduce($keywords, function ($match_found, $keyword) use ($title) {
        return $match_found || found_keyword($keyword, $title);
    }, FALSE);
}
```

To create an array of keywords from a string of comma-separated words:

```
$keywords = split(',', $comma_separated_string);
```

Comment: thanks! i tried these but i get errors. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: It depends on where you declare those functions; I pasted them into an empty PHP-documents and they worked for me. Maybe if you have a PHP version that doesn't support anonymous functions it can protest too, since there is one such in the found_keyword's array_reduce.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be usefull for you [Grabbing title of a website using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869925/grabbing-title-of-a-website-using-dom)

After you get title as string you can simply use explode function

Comment: uhhmmmmm how do i do that?